# Python beginner w/ a fundamental question: How to call classes and methods correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, class

I've just covered Classes, Objects, and Polymorphisms and how to create them. But I'm struggling to understand the syntax within Classes and how objects are called. I'll illustrate one of the exercises that asks:

> Define a class named Shape and its subclass Square. The Square class has an init function which takes a length as an argument. Both classes have an area function that can print the area of the shape where the Shape's area is 0 by default.

The provided solution is as follows:

```
class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def area(self):
        return 0

class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, l):
        Shape.__init__(self)
        self.length = l

    def area(self):
        return self.length*self.length

aSquare = Square(3)
print (aSquare.area())
```

Q1: This block is really confusing me.

```
class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, l):
        Shape.__init__(self)
        self.length = l
```

I know by including `(Shape)` we inherit its methods. But why is the variable `l` used instead of just `length`? Edit: When I replace `l` with `length` it outputs `NameError: name 'l' not defined`.

Q2: Why is `Shape` used in `Shape.__init__(self)`? For some reason I want to write `self.__init__(self)` but that's obviously wrong. Most of the examples I've run through create an object, then call the method `object.method()`. But here it's an entire Class. I can backtrack the code and it makes sense as to how it works. But I don't understand the fundamental purpose and function of `self` and how the syntax of `X` work within `X.__init__(self)`.

Much thanks for all the time and help. I'm very sorry for the long winded question. I'm having difficulty isolating what exactly is throwing me off but I hope I'm making some sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: `l` is a parameter of Square's constructor that gets assigned to Square's instance variable `length`. `self` implies an instance of a class (in this case Square). `aSquare = Square(3)`, `aSquare` is actually `self` and `l` is `3` and then `l` gets assigned to `self.length` that is `aSquare.length = 3`. If you do `print(aSquare.length)` you'll get `3`. `l` can be named any valid name, even `length` itself.

Q2: Since `Square` is inheriting from `Shape`, `Shape's` constructor has to be called in order to initialize itself, so the line `Shape.__init__(self)` is actually calling `Shape's` constructor, that is its `def __init__(self)` method. As already said `self` implies an instance of a class. You can see that instance method all have `self` parameter, but when calling the method you pass nothing at the place as an argument. Look at the definition of `area` method and the way it's called.

```
def area(self):
    return self.length*self.length

aSquare.area()
```

`area` requires a paremeter but none is provided. Because it's implied, since aSquare represents `self`. You could have done it other way around. Calling `area` from a class and providing `aSquare` as an argument.

```
Square.area(aSquare)
```

But if you do `Square.area()` you'll get an error.

Comment: Much thanks for this. To clarify, why is `Shape's` constructor even passed to Square? `Shape` doesn't seem to be to doing anything? Lastly, what do you mean that `area` requires a parameter? If I'm understanding this correctly, `area` is using the `length` property of `Sqaure's` `__init__`? You've clarified a lot, thank you very much.

Comment: When defining a function everything inside parenthesis is called parameters. When the function is called, one must provide arguments at the place of parameters. When `area` was defined there is `self` parameter, which implies an instance of a class.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I mean why would `Square` even inherit `Shape` for functionality? What's the purpose of doing that to calculate the needed area?

Comment: `Shape's` constructor is called inside `Square` because `Square` inherits from `Shape`. By inheriting from `Shape` it inherits all of its members (fields & methods), so for an instance of `Square` to have all those inherited members they must be somehow initialized, that's where `Shape's` constructor jumps in and initializes all of its members so that they are at the disposition to `Square's` instances.

Comment: You should recall the benefits of inheritance.

Comment: Yeah, so I just removed the entire class `Shape` from the code and it runs exactly the same. So I'm curious why they even solved it this way. But that's maybe besides the point. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know what was the purpose of the exercise. But the `Shape` class is an abstraction, it defines common things that shapes have. All shapes do have area (square, triangle etc.). Since area is common to all shapes it is defined there, so you do not repeat code in descendants or to tell that every descendant has to have it. But since area is differently calculated for every shape you need to override area in each shape. So the `area` in `Square` is actually overriding the `area` in `Shape` to provide the meaningful implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question relates to the `__init__` method of a class. In python `__init__` will be called any time you instantiate an object from a class. When you call

```
b = Square(3)
```

Python creates a new Square object, whose length variable, which is the second parameter of the `__init__` function, will be initialized to 3. Inside the definition of `__init__`.

```
def __init__(self, length):
    self.length = length
```

the first argument refers to the object of class Square and the second argument is the length argument. If you rename length to l, you need to rename it everywhere

```
 def __init__(self, l):
    self.length = l
```

For your second question, read up on inheritance. Basically your second class Square is inheriting from the first class shape. In the `__init__` method it calls the `__init__` of the first class Shape. You can replace

```
Shape.__init__(self)
```

with

```
super().__init__()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

Comment: So `self.length` can be `self.anything`? In the solution they used `(self, l)` but then equated `self.length = l`. Basically `length` is not `l` but it still worked. How's is that?

Comment: @Aisync `self.length` means length is a property of the Square object. You can call the property by any name, but it will be shared by all objects of type Square. If you define `obj = Square(3)`, then `obj.length` will be equal to 3. In your init function if you change the name of the property to something else, say `self.side`, then `obj.side` is the name of the new property. `l` is just a function parameter, it can have any name. Similarly `self` is just a convention in Python to call the object of the class. You can give it any name as long as it is the first parameter of the method